# Bullet energy loss in solid materials

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, projectile

Does someone know simple model of energy loss in solid materials for a solid bullet?

For example: I want to estimate momentum transferred to a thin plastic plate given by a small bullet. No matter how difficult model is. But it should depend only on plate/projectile parameters?

**EDIT:**

No precise solution is needed. It is interesting to know order of energy transfer. 
One simple model that i suggested was model of exponential suppression:
$$ {\delta E}(r) \approx E_{0} e^{ - \frac{r}{d} } $$
where $d$ is a "terminal length" - after crossing this length bullet loses $e$ units of energy. So, knowing max distance in material one can find parameter $d$

It is not obvious that this formula is close to reality, but it is first step. Also it is not clear if one can use this formula for thin plates.

I have no experience solving such problems, so i asked if someone can point me (links, books, ideas).

Comment: Have you tried to find it in some ballistics books?

Comment: It depends if there is bending, denting, fracturing and ripping involved. Each absorbs energy and the details are too complex for [Physics.SE].

Comment: I tried to read some papers but there are a lot of formulas with additional parameters. One can't simply find values of these parameters in google.